# How to transform a JSON string to NSArray

Tags: ios

Here is a response I get from a server:

```
{
    result = {
        blankfill = "[[1, [u'32354'], False, 7]]";
        choice = "[[13, [3], False, 11], [10, [0], False, 3], [9, [1], False, 3], [2, [2], False, 4], [3, [1], False, 3], [1, [2], False, 3]]";
        spendTime = 26;
    };
    retcode = 0;
    subjectid = 1;
    submittime = "2016-05-24T15:21:50.784"; 
}
```

`choice` is the string I want to convert to `NSArray`, it also contains nested arrays.

Here is the code I tried:

```
 NSString *jsonString = [responseObject[@"result"] objectForKey:@"choice"];
 NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Currently, `arr` is always nil.

Comment: "You can see that, choice is a NSString actually stands for a NSArray also containing nested array" It's just a string containing some commas and brackets.

Comment: You always get nil, because that's not a JSON, JSON does not have `False` as value, see [json.org](http://www.json.org). However, it would have `false`. `u'32354'` is also not a value.

Comment: @simpleBob: The False is just five characters within a string. The key "choice" has a string value "[[13, [3], False..."

Comment: @gnasher729 yes, it's just five characters in a string, but when `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` is called, it should gets transformed, but it can't be transformed because it is not a valid JSON, since `False` doesn't exist in JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change `False` to `false` everywhere in your string. Then it will parse as JSON.

(It seems likely that something is wrong at the server end, though. Presumably this is supposed to be a JSON array to start with, and because of this capitalization mistake, it is arriving as a string instead.)

```
NSString* s = @"[[13, [3], false, 11], [10, [0], false, 3], [9, [1], false, 3], [2, [2], false, 4], [3, [1], false, 3], [1, [2], false, 3]]";
NSData *data = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError* err;
NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&err];
NSLog(@"%@", arr);
```

Logs:

```
(
        (
        13,
                (
            3
        ),
        0,
        11
    ),
        (
        10,
                (
            0
        ),
        0,
        3
    ),
        (
        9,
                (
            1
        ),
        0,
        3
    ),
        (
        2,
                (
            2
        ),
        0,
        4
    ),
        (
        3,
                (
            1
        ),
        0,
        3
    ),
        (
        1,
                (
            2
        ),
        0,
        3
    )
)
```

Comment: It works. Sorry I didn't notice the False. I get the response from Python restful server. True/False is valid in python, so I think they just return String format for their Boolean field. Sorry for the noise. I will accept the answer.

Comment: The real problem with your code was `error:nil`. The error was explaining to you what the problem was, but you were throwing away the error without reading it.

Comment: See [Introducing JSON](http://www.json.org), only `true`,
`false` and
`null` are valid literal values, not `True` and `False`. What Python accepts is beside the point. As @matt points out, error message are your friend, use them.

Comment: Yes,you are right. I will pay more attention to those error message.